# Mysql table lists rows not in order

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Today I inserted a row in a mysql table but something strange happened because the last added row with higher primary id is before some other rows with lower id and after some other rows with lower id like this:

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|   1     |
|   50    |
|   69    | <=== Wrong place
|   63    |
+---------+
```

This is how it is listed in phpmyadmin, and in my php script. I understand that if I dont define in my php script in which order to list the rows but in phpmyadmin I dont know why is this happening. btw this is the first time I see something like this.

This is the result of the query: SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing user_id of each user,
     unique index',  `web_id` varchar(166) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s name',
    `user_password_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password in salted and hashed format',
    `user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email',
    `domain` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `address` varchar(166) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `billing_firstname` varchar(166) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `billing_lastname` varchar(166) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `billing_phone` varchar(90) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `billing_country` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `git_auto_update` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
    `server_id` int(16) NOT NULL,
    `trial` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `purchase_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data'
```

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable`\G  and run `SELECT * FROM mytable` and post the output of both.

Comment: please read [MY POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) on how to properly ask a question... it will help you get an appropriate answer

Comment: also the order that the rows are inserted in the table shouldn't matter. when you run a SELECT statement just use ORDER BY to ensure its order like you already should be doing. and the PRIMARY id should be auto incremented not sure why you would be specifying it yourself.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA check out the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE in the question thnx

Comment: @JohnRuddell even though it is not a situation to panic but the moment I saw this I got confused so I wrote my question really fast

Comment: @TooCooL no problem.. you can edit the question and just add information in.. it will make it so other passers by can understand the question and how to solve it with the answers as well.. think of your question as a piece of art. it needs to be worked on until its a masterpiece :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess but here it goes...

Your table layout is

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing user_id of each user,
     unique index',  `web_id` varchar(166) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s name',
    `user_password_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password in salted and hashed format',
    `user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email',
    `domain` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `address` varchar(166) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `billing_firstname` varchar(166) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `billing_lastname` varchar(166) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `billing_phone` varchar(90) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `billing_country` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `git_auto_update` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
    `server_id` int(16) NOT NULL,
    `trial` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `purchase_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data'
```

My gut feeling says the the `user_id` values are coming out in `user_name` order. This happens sometimes when there is both a PRIMARY KEY and a UNIQUE KEY. You can verify this by running

```
SELECT user_id,user_name FROM users;
SELECT user_id,user_name FROM users ORDER BY user_id;
SELECT user_id,user_name FROM users ORDER BY user_name;
```

and comparing the output

Comment: Yes that is what I thought so but I changed the user_name to non unique key and still the problem is not solved I am going to test it more to see what is the problem.

Comment: I tried SELECT web_id FROM users and the output was the same as my problem, so I guess the problem is with web_id